# SASS error: can't import Compass

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I've been using sass and compass on this computer for a few months with no issues.

Additionally, my config.rb and sass directories have always been set up the same way, and they're the same on all of my projects.

Recently, I started getting this error in Sublime when I build the sass: `Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: compass.`

The first line of my .scss file is `@import "compass";`, so I see this error in Terminal: `error sass/style.scss (Line 36 of _vertical_rhythm.scss: Incompatible units: 'px' and 'em'.)`

I've been searching for days, and I see answers around some of this stuff (the vertical-rhythm specifically), but nothing is my exact problem, and I can't find a solution.

My compass version is 0.12.5 (Alnilam), and my sass version is 3.3.4 (Maptastic Maple).

At work, everything compiles fine with the exact same files, working from the exact same GitHub repo. I need to check my versions of compass and sass at work tomorrow, but in the meantime, I'm stumped.

Any ideas? Has this happened to anyone?

Comment: Compass 0.12.5 is not compatible with Sass 3.3+

Comment: Thanks. I tried Sass 3.2.5 instead, and I'm getting the same error.

Sass at work is 3.2.5, but I didn't double check that Compass is the same version, so I'll do that tomorrow.

Comment: i answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108679/sasssyntaxerror-file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-compass-in-production/23122076#23122076

Comment: Thanks, @whatbird, but still no luck for me... At this point, I've tried many different combinations of sass and compass, but I think my lack of ruby/gem/terminal knowledge is holding me back in figuring this out.

Comment: I've never built SASS scripts through Sublime, but I would check that it is not the load path that is biting you. Especially if you have multiple different Rubies and gempaths on your system (through RVM, rbenv, ...), make sure you change/update the SASS and compass libraries Sublime actually uses.

Comment: It sounds to me like there is a version mismatch between Sass and Compass. Try installing the latest beta version of Compass: `gem install compass --pre`. Otherwise, please give us the Sass code, and Sass and Compass versions, which are causing the error.

Comment: gem install compass --pre gave me this error...

`ERROR:  Error installing compass:

ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb

mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.3 for inspection.

Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/ffi-1.9.3/gem_make.out`

Comment: I've tried all different version combinations, but currently I'm using Sass 3.2.5 and Compass 0.12.5.

The Sass that causes the error is the first line of my .scss file... just `@import compass;`

Thanks @KatieK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a month of troubleshooting, the solution ended up being simpler than expected.

I uninstalled all versions of both Sass and Compass, and then I installed the latest Compass and let it install Sass automatically.

So after doing `sudo gem uninstall compass` and `sudo gem uninstall sass`, I did `sudo gem install compass`. That installed both Compass and its dependencies (Sass version 3.2.19). (I'm on a Mac, so I had to use `sudo`.)

Solved!

Answer (score 1):

if this is on mac:

Go to:

`/var/folders/p_/w19t0k956zz_bg0bgs0cn6200000gn/T/liferay`

and delete following folders:

`document_preview`  `document_thumbnail`    `ruby`